# Getting my web server to send an email on behalf of my mail server

Tags: php, email, cross-domain, postfix-mta

So, I have a separate web server and mail server configured for the same domain (web.example.com & mail.example.com, each with different IPs). The reason I did this was so that I could use CloudFlare to deliver my web content while protecting my origin IP. I understand that my mail server's IP is exposed, this is alright for the time being.

The issue I am facing is that if an email originates from my web server (let's say for instance a user forgets their login details, and my web server triggers a recovery email to be sent)... this will expose my web server's origin IP in the headers of the email sent to the user.

What I need to be able to do, is either one of the following, I am also open to other suggestions:

1) Masquerade as the IP of web.example.com

2) Trigger an email to be sent from mail.example.com

Both servers have PostFix and Dovecot configured.

I am using PHP to trigger mails to be sent.

Comment: so, what exactly is so bad about the *public* IP-address of your server appearing in the header of a mail - which 99.99....% of users don't even know exists? regarding the original question: there are *many* ways, but SO is not here to get you started on ideas, but help you with problems. in its current form, the question is **far too broad**

Comment: Apart from that: your web server is public, that is the whole purpose of that web server. There is nothing to be kept secret there.

Comment: Did you guys miss the part about CloudFlare? CloudFlare hides my web server's IP. The email is what is leaking my origin IP.

Comment: @Jay no we did not miss that part. but did you miss the part where we asked what is so bad about *not* hiding it? the part asking *why* you hide your IP?

Comment: The mail.example.com origin IP can be public, that is its purpose. The web server's origin IP is protected by CloudFlare's proxy. This is to avoid the possibility of my web server being hit with a direct DDoS. Attackers would need to launch an attack on CloudFlare's servers, not mine.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I host my site with Digital Ocean, if it is hit with a DDoS the server will be taken down for a period of time (I think it is 24 hours). That is why my web server can not leak the origin IP. This is really not an uncommon issue, it is basically one of the key features of CloudFlare, hiding the origin.

Comment: @Jay no matter how well you hide it, in time, the IP **will** leak. so it's much better to protect at the base in the first place - for example instruct IPtables to instantly drop every incomming connection that doesn't originate from CF. (and as an idea how you might get started on your question: write your mails in a queue, and let a script on the mailserver work it off and send the mails, instead of your main server sending it directly)

Comment: Thanks :) Will look into queuing outgoing mails in a database on my mail server. Will run a cronjob to send them out. Reluctant to do the IPtables method because that can potentially get you locked out of your own server (http://serverfault.com/a/481364/323295).